# My queries are too slow. How to perform and speed up them?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I have two queries on tables with milions of rows.. is possible speed them up?

The first is this:

```
WITH DATI AS
(
    SELECT 
        a.target_ou_id  FK_CLIENTE, count(*) QTA_NUM_TENT_VEND_3M
    FROM
        STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_EVT_ACT_G A 
    LEFT JOIN  
        STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_EVT_ACT_X_G ax ON A.ROW_ID = AX.ROW_ID
    WHERE
        INITCAP (ax.attrib_03) = 'Tentativo Di Vendita'
        AND to_number(to_char(todo_plan_start_dt,'YYYYMMDD')) >= to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate,-3),'YYYYMMDD'))
    GROUP BY 
        a.target_ou_id
), IND_NBA AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CDC_QUERY, PK_ID_IND_NBA, SDS_NOME_ORA 
    FROM 
        ODS.T_ODS_ALL_DIM_IND_NBA 
    WHERE 
        CDC_QUERY = 'CRM038' AND SDS_STATO = 'ATT'
)
, PIVOT AS 
(
   SELECT
       FK_CLIENTE,
       IND_NBA.CDC_QUERY  CDC_QUERY,
       IND_NBA.SDS_NOME_ORA  CD_IND_NBA,
       IND_NBA.PK_ID_IND_NBA,
       DECODE(IND_NBA.SDS_NOME_ORA,
                    'QTA_NUM_TENT_VEND_3M ', QTA_NUM_TENT_VEND_3M,
                     NULL) AS CDN_VALORE,
       NULL AS SDS_TESTO 
   FROM 
       DATI
   CROSS JOIN 
       IND_NBA
)
SELECT * 
FROM PIVOT
WHERE CDN_VALORE IS NOT NULL or SDS_TESTO IS NOT NULL
```

The second is this:

```
WITH DATI AS
(
    SELECT 
        CLI_UNICO.FK_CLIENTE FK_CLIENTE,
        MAX(CASE WHEN COM.LDS_DESCRIZIONE_COMUNE IS NOT NULL THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END) FLC_COMUNE_TERR
    FROM    
        STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G A, 
        ODS.V_ODS_NBA_DT_ASS_CLI_CLIUNICO CLI_UNICO,
        STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ORG_EXT_G CFORN,
        STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ADDR_PER_G IND_FOR,
        STG.T_STG_PSP_DT_LISTA_COMUNI_TERR COM
    WHERE 
        A.OWNER_ACCNT_ID = CLI_UNICO.FK_CLIENTE
        AND A.SERV_ACCT_ID = CFORN.ROW_ID(+)
        AND CFORN.PR_ADDR_ID = IND_FOR.ROW_ID(+)
        AND IND_FOR.CITY = COM. LDS_DESCRIZIONE_COMUNE (+)
    GROUP BY 
        CLI_UNICO.FK_CLIENTE
)
, IND_NBA AS
(
   SELECT 
       CDC_QUERY, PK_ID_IND_NBA, SDS_NOME_ORA 
   FROM 
       ODS.T_ODS_ALL_DIM_IND_NBA 
   WHERE 
       CDC_QUERY = 'CRM036' AND SDS_STATO = 'ATT'
)
, PIVOT AS (
    SELECT
       FK_CLIENTE,
       IND_NBA.CDC_QUERY  CDC_QUERY,
       IND_NBA.SDS_NOME_ORA  CD_IND_NBA,
       IND_NBA.PK_ID_IND_NBA,
       NULL AS CDN_VALORE,
       DECODE(IND_NBA.SDS_NOME_ORA,
                    'FLC_COMUNE_TERR', FLC_COMUNE_TERR,
                     NULL) AS SDS_TESTO 
   FROM 
       DATI
   CROSS JOIN 
       IND_NBA
)
SELECT * 
FROM PIVOT
WHERE CDN_VALORE IS NOT NULL or SDS_TESTO IS NOT NULL
```

I put indexes on join columns

```
offerte.target_ou_id,
CLI_UNICO.FK_CLIENTE,
A.OWNER_ACCNT_ID,CLI_UNICO.FK_CLIENTE,
A.SERV_ACCT_ID,CFORN.ROW_ID,
CFORN.PR_ADDR_ID, IND_FOR.ROW_ID,
IND_FOR.CITY,COM.LDS_DESCRIZIONE_COMUNE
```

The tables have these numbers of rows:

- STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_EVT_ACT_G A->314mil
- STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_EVT_ACT_X_G->321mil
- STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G A ->25 mil.
- ODS.V_ODS_NBA_DT_ASS_CLI_CLIUNICO CLI_UNICO->12,3 mil
- STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ORG_EXT_G CFORN->74,6mil
- STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ADDR_PER_G IND_FOR->56 mil
- STG.T_STG_PSP_DT_LISTA_COMUNI_TERR COM->161
- ind_nba->463

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe they can be sped up? Any leads, or ideas as to where the problem areas are? These are really big queries to just dump on complete strangers.

Comment: Also, the biggest problem is probably those cross joins. Any reason you need the Cartesian product of what is probably going to be millions of records?

Comment: cross join on ind_nba take only 1 record with CDC_QUERY='CRM03X' and sds_stato=att

Comment: ^[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to consider:
Learn  to use `tkprof`

At the start of the code add

```
alter session set sql_trace true;
```

At the end of your code add

```
alter session set sql_trace false;
```

Run the code (I am assuming it actually runs with no errors).  Remember exactly the ime of day when it finished.

Next get some DBA help.  In the `$ORACLE_HOME/admin/[name of database]` there is usually (for development db's) a directory called udump.  In there will be a file name

```
[ some numbers].trc
```

That has a file time of exactly when your code stopped running.

run the `tkprof` executable against the file

```
tkprof 123456789.trc some_output_filename
```

The output file displays information for the executed times, disk lookup & i/o, and the explain plan used for each cursor.